# Need help converting c# XOR to Java

Tags: c#, java, ascii, xor

A developer that has since left created a little log obfuscation program that I need to convert to java.

All char items have been xor'ed by 255, here is the de'obfuscation code snippet

```
char[] array = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){
    char @string = array[i];
     text2 += Conversions.ToString(Strings.Chr(Strings.Asc(@string) ^ 255));
}
streamWriter.WriteLine(text2);
```

I need to convert this `Conversions.ToString(Strings.Chr(Strings.Asc(@string) ^ 255));` from c# to java.  The problem is that in java if the ascii character is > 255, seems to not decode the character correctly.  Here is an example:

```
String e = "ÃÎÌËÁßÍÏÎÌÐÏÉÐÎÌßÎÊÒÌÈÒÌÇßÃ“œž“ÏÑ–‘™Áß‘ŠÎÏÈÈËÑ‘ŠŒ–šÑœ’ß™ÅßÏÌÌÉ"; 
    String sOut1 = ""; 
    String sOut2 = "'";
    char[] cArray = e.toCharArray();
    for(int index = 0; index < cArray.length; index++){
        int before = ((int) cArray[index]);
        int after = before ^ 255;
        char s = ((char) after);
        sOut1 += cArray[index];
        sOut2 += Character.toString(s);
        System.out.println( "1: " + cArray[index] + 
                            "  2: " + Integer.toString(before) + 
                            "  3: " + Integer.toString(after) +
                            "  4: " + Character.toString(s)

                );


    }
    System.out.println(sOut1);
    System.out.println(sOut2);
```

Here is the output of my java code:

```
ÃÎÌËÁßÍÏÎÌÐÏÉÐÎÌßÎÊÒÌÈÒÌÇßÃ“œž“ÏÑ–‘™Áß‘ŠÎÏÈÈËÑ‘ŠŒ–šÑœ’ß™ÅßÏÌÌÉ
```

'<134> 2013/06/13 15-37-38 <⃣oƬƁ⃣0.⃬⃧⇝o> ⃧Ɵ10774.⃧Ɵƭp⃬rƞ.Ƭo⃦ p⇝

Thanks for the assistance and any help given.

Comment: What is `Strings` and `Conversions`? Those don't sound like framework types...

Comment: Maybe You're looking for String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") and new String(byte[], "ISO-8859-1")

Answer (score -1):

Try to get only the lower 8 bits of the Java char. You could do that by masking:

```
char tmp&=255;
```

Or using the modulus operator to mask it:

```
char tmp=tmp%255;
```

Comment: Ermir, is there anyway that you could point me to more information on that, or a small example?  Thanks